# TimeInterval型からmm:ss.ffのString型への変換

Tags: swift, swift3

たとえば`timeInterval = 124.04521142`という数値を
`02:04.04`というString型の値にしたいのですが、
フォーマットについての理解が浅いためか、以下のように初心者ながらに冗長気味なのがわかります・・・

```
let min = timeInterval / 60
let sec = Int(timeInterval.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60))

let timeIntervalInteger = Int(timeInterval)
let decimal = timeInterval - Double(timeIntervalInteger)
    //timeInterval全体から整数のみを引いて小数だけを取り出す

let decimalInteger = Int(decimal * 100)
    //小数の"0."を取り除くため、100倍して小数点以下を切り捨てる

let minSec = String(format: "%02d:%02d%", min, sec)
    //まずmm:ssフォーマットにする

let miliSec = String(format: "%02d", decimalInteger)
    //ミリ秒をffのフォーマットにする

var str = minSec + "." + miliSec

print(str)
```

timeIntervalからわざわざ整数部分を引いた上でそれを１００倍してから`"%02d`のフォーマットで`"."`を足すというのはものすごい遠回りな気がします・・・。

`timeInterval`をタイマーで0.01秒ごとに１増える整数として扱えば計算は楽になるとは思うのですが、扱いたいものが再生中の曲の現在の再生時間（`currentPlaybackTime`）で、
TimeInterval型で引き出しているので、少数 -> mm:ss.ffにしたいのです。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/92953

Answer (score 0):

最初にお断りしておきますが、これは、ご質問に直接お答えするものではありません。`TimeInterval`型の変数を、フォーマットされた文字列に変換するのは、わざわざプログラムを新規に作らなくても、既存のものの流用で行えますよ、という回答になります。

```
// どこか（たとえばクラスのプロパティとして）にインスタンスformatterを保持。
var formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "mm:ss.SS"

// フォーマットされた文字列に変換するプログラム。
let timeInterval = 124.04521142
let targetDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: timeInterval)
let str = formatter.string(from: targetDate)
```

詳細は、`DateFormatter`クラス、`Date`クラスのリファレンスをご覧ください。

Comment: DateFormatterで得られるのは時刻のフォーマットなので今回のような経過時間をフォーマットする場合には適さないことがあります。具体的には60分を超える場合は希望した結果が得られません。60分を超えない条件下なら問題ないと思います。